# Unable to validate your application. the package does not contain an info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode6, info.plist

I have just finished my application. It runs fine on all devices that I tested it on. It archives successfully as well. However, when I try to validate it in the Xcode organizer I am met with the following errors:

> -Unable to validate your application: The package does not contain an info.plist

I checked my project files, and I do see an info.plist file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This unfortunate error message probably means that some key is missing in your *info.plist*.

I compared my *info.plist* source-file (right click the file  and select view source) with the corresponding file in another project. I then discovered that, in my case, the following key was missing:

```
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
```

I pasted in those two lines in my *info.plist* file, and then it all worked fine.

Beware that you probably have *two info.plist-files* in your project (the second one is for the unit test build) and make sure that you compare the right ones.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had less than 5 GB free space, cleaning up and archiving again solved it.

Comment: This answer works for me. Wondering about the reason behind it.

Comment: Space was an issue for me too, I didn't need to archive again though. Just tried re-uploading and it worked

Comment: The same situation